# conflicting types for 'gettimeofday' while building newlib for cross compiler

Tags: c, cross-compiling, osdev

while trying to build newlib 1.20.0...
i followed this tutorial http://wiki.osdev.org/OS_Specific_Toolchain#newlib.2Flibc.2Fsys.2Fmyos

but when trying to build newlib i get the following error:

```
/../newlib-1.20.0/newlib/libc/sys/myos/'`syscalls.c
../../../../../../newlib-1.20.0/newlib/libc/sys/myos/syscalls.c:29:5: error: conflicting types for 'gettimeofday'
In file included from ../../../../../../newlib-1.20.0/newlib/libc/sys/myos/syscalls.c:7:0:
/usr/src/newlib-1.20.0/newlib/libc/include/sys/time.h:74:5: note: previous declaration of 'gettimeofday' was here
Makefile:280: recipe for target `lib_a-syscalls.o' failed
```

sycalls.c for gettimeofday declaration :

```
int gettimeofday(struct timeval *p, struct timezone *z);
```

time.h :

```
int _EXFUN(gettimeofday, (struct timeval *__p, void *__tz));
```

so what is conflicting type??please help....any help is appreciated...

Comment: The conflict here is that the declaration in syscalls.c specifies  the second argument as `struct timezone *` while in time.h it's `void *`. The one in syscalls.c is the correct.

Comment: but isn't void * suppose to accept any type of pointer...??

Comment: Yes, but if the compiler sees both it's still different (and therefore conflicting) types because while a void pointer can be used to accept all kind of pointers it's a distinct type that is not the same as a `struct timezone` pointer.

Comment: but changing the type to struct timezone in time.h is giving the same error but at another place....so it seems i cannot change it...what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Change *your* declaration of the function in syscalls.c. Then cast the void * to a struct timezone.